# How to import a module from a different folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have a project which I want to structure like this:

```
myproject
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── api.py
├── backend
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── backend.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_model.py
└── __init__.py
```

Now, I want to import the module `some_model.py` in both `api.py` and `backend.py`. How do I properly do this?

I tried:

```
from models import some_model
```

but that fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`.

I also tried:

```
from ..models import some_model
```

which gave me `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I import a file from a different directory, which is not a subdirectory?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Firstly, this import statement:

```py
from models import some_model
```

should be namespaced:

```py
# in myproject/backend/backend.py or myproject/api/api.py
from myproject.models import some_model
```

Then you will need to get the directory which contains `myproject`, let's call this `/path/to/parent`, into the `sys.path` list.  You can do this temporarily by setting an environment variable:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent
```

Or, preferably, you can do it by writing a `setup.py` file and installing your package.  Follow the [PyPA](https://packaging.python.org/) packaging guide.  After you have written your `setup.py` file, from within the same directory, execute this to setup the correct entries in `sys.path`:

```py
pip install --editable .
```

Comment: This will work, but you should also be able to do a relative import from within the `myproject` package, which OP has tried. What would cause that not to work?

Comment: That has been covered a billion times over at [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/674039), so I won't go into it again.

Comment: you think OP is running `api.py` as a script? that would explain it, yes

Comment: I guess I'll dive into the PyPA packaging guide then =)

Comment: I created a package and installed it using pip install --editable as suggested. Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: This answer really helped me. Although I’ve seen similar answers on many other similar questions, I couldn’t believe you have to install the package _you want to develop_ itself. That is – at least for me – _highly_ contra intuitive. Your answer clarified it.

Comment: After doing `pip install --editable .` if we made a change on any file under the imported folder, should we do `pip install --editable .` again to fetch the new updates?

Comment: @alper  it should not be necessary. The whole point of the —editable installation is that you are able to edit the installed code directly.

Answer (score 32):

Unfortunately, Python will only find your file if your file is in the systems path. But fear not! There is a way around this!

Using python's `sys` module, we can add a directory to the path while Python is running just for the current run of the program.  This will not affect any other Python programs run later.

You can do this by:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('relative/path/to/application/folder'))
import [file]
```

It is important to import sys and set the directory path before you import the file.

If your library is NOT close to the current directory, an absolute path could be simpler:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/absolute/path/to/application/folder'))
import [file]
```

Yes, this is a hack. But it can be helpful as a short-term work-around.

Comment: Changing the path from within code, though possible, is messy and bad - it makes the test setup more difficult and makes the import ordering become significant.

Comment: Ah, when will python solve this problem, why python 3.10 still not solve this problem, is this very difficult ?

Comment: Yes, this is a hack.

Comment: It would be useful to convert a relative path to an absolute one. `import os` and `os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")` will accomplish this.

Comment: @WadeWang This is fundamentally a system configuration issue.  Package managers like pip should help.  Or package *development* managers -- but I don't have much experience with those.

This is a useful hack. That doesn't mean I recommend it for any code that we intend to have last!

Answer (score 5):

I would lay out two approaches:

Simply import `some_model` via absolute importing:

```py
from myproject.models import some_model
```

Note that the `myproject` should be treated as an module (i.e. having `__init__.py`)

---

Or

You can add the previous path to the `sys.path` which I use in such parallel level modules:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from models import some_model
```