# How can i solve the Error when importing local Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

I want to import a local module, which is located in a different folder. I imported like this:

```
from .utils.embeds import Embeds
```

Which works, but my IDE shows this:

```
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please check this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039436/how-to-import-a-module-from-a-different-folder

does it help ?

Comment: honstly not really, i dont really unterstand what the error message means