# importing a parent folder python script for subfolder script (no sys.path workaround please)

Tags: python, import, module, package, subdirectory

With this structure:

```
my-project/
|--- useful_functions.py/
|--- subfolder/
    |--- script.py
```

How to allow `script.py` to access the `useful_functions.py` (one level up), preferably NOT using `sys.path` for this?
My cousin says I should simple put my-project folder into anaconda's site-packages and then use `import my-project.useful_functions`, is that good practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Thanks for this link. The answer from almost 9 years ago does not address what I am asking. After a painful read it concludes "the package directory .. must be accessible from the Python module search path (`sys.path`). If it is not, you will not be able to use anything in the package reliably at all." I refuse to believe almost a decade later this is still the case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer seems to be:

(1) Create this structure:

```
my-project/
| setup.py
| __init__.py
|--- useful_functions/
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- useful.py
|--- subfolder/
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- script.py
```

The `__init__.py` files can be empty.
The setup.py file [apparently](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example) needs only:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='my-project',
      version='0.1',
      py_modules=['my-project'],
      )
```

(2) In `my-project/` execute `pip3 install -e .`

Now `script.py` can use:

```
from useful_functions.useful import useful_fn
```

This comes partly from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039436/how-to-import-a-module-from-a-different-folder) and lots of trial-and-error, and IMHO is far more complicated than it needs to be.  Happy to see easier and better approaches from others.

Also, if you need to import from a sibling file in `useful_functions`, like:

```
|--- useful_functions/
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- useful.py
     |--- useful2.py
```

in `useful2.py` it would be:

```
from .useful_functions.useful import useful_fn
```