# How to read a file with relative path from a file inside a sub-folder in python

Tags: python

I have a folder structure as below

```
root
  ->module
    -> __init__.py
    -> lib
       -> data.pk
    -> read.py
  ->script
     -> __init__.py
     -> inner.py
  ->outer.py
```

read.py has below code

```
with open(r"./lib/data.pk", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)`
```

Now when I `import module.read` in **outer.py** file, it successfully opens `./lib/data.pk` file

However when I try to `import module.read` in **inner.py** file, i get an error
`Module does not exist: 'module.read'`

I then appended the parent directory to `sys.path` using below code

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

and the I was able to `import module.read` successfully. However when I execute the **inner.py** file I get an error `No such file or directory: './lib/data.pk'`

Since I have added the parent directory to `sys.path`, I was expecting **inner.py** to open and read `'./lib/data.pk' file.`

Kindly let me know, how can I read `'./lib/data.pk'` file from **inner.py** file

Comment: Do you have any code inside `__init__.py`? And how do you execute **outter.py**?

Comment: There is no code inside __init__.py. I execute outter.py by simple python command

Comment: Did you try my solution? If yes, did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change code to this:

```py
with open(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/lib/data.pk", "rb") as f:
```

If this doesn't work, follow the steps below:

Add this to **inner.py** in the beggining:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
```

And add an `__init__.py` to the *root* folder.

Read more from here: [How to import a module from a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039436/how-to-import-a-module-from-a-different-folder)