# Can't import python file from a different package

Tags: python, python-import

This seems like the most trivial thing ever, but it is simply not working for me.

My project structure is as follows:

```
src
 |-- auth
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- auth.py
 |-- models
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- messaging.py
```

I want to be able to import auth.py from messaging.py. I have tried the following in my code:

```
import auth
from auth import auth
from ..auth import auth
from src.auth import auth
from auth.auth import *
```

None of these work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module from a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039436/how-to-import-a-module-from-a-different-folder)

Comment: Resolved my issue by creating a main file in src. I am importing files I want to run in main, using it as my "project root."

This is fine for me, because I'm planning to have a main file from which everything is run anyway.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 3):

Resolved my issue by creating a `main.py` file in src. In main, I am importing .py files I want to run. That runs the file from the location of main, which means I can now import my auth package and its modules.

`main.py` literally just contains `from models import messaging`.

Comment: Great choice! In your question you have set auth and models as a package by __init__.py. So in the end (even unwantedly) you have already prepared yourself for such step. Usually you want to keep at least one "traffic managing .py" at the very top.       Either way you can still use sys.path.insert(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can help you.

1. Create `__init__.py` file in the src module
2. modify your import instructions in the `messaging.py` like this:

```
from src.auth import auth
```

3. use auth functionality